# Is it possible to set owners to 'any' for a aws_ami resource?

Tags: terraform

I am trying to `terraform plan` against a tf file which contains this code:

```
data "aws_ami" "Windows_2016" {
  filter {
    name   = "is-public"
    values = ["false"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["windows2016Server*"]
  }

  most_recent = true
}
```

Error: data.aws_ami.Windows_2016: "owners": required field is not set

It stills fail if I run

```
 terraform plan -var "owners=[]"
```

I don't have any data of `owners` because

1. I did not build any window 2016 ami myself
2. I do not care about the owner

It is possible to tell terraform that I dont' worry about `owners`? Some sort of wildcard `*`, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
owners - (Required) List of AMI owners to limit search. **At least 1 value must be specified**. Valid values: an AWS account ID, self (the current account), or an AWS owner alias (e.g. amazon, aws-marketplace, microsoft).
```

Reference : https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ami.html

Since one value is must, so I think you can give **self**